# comparing values from a JSON object in python in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a JSON format object, that I receive from a user from an API body. When stored and checked its type in Python it says dict. But the keys within the dict are stored as a set.

```
x = {'test': {'shipmentInfo': {'Ready Date', 'Ready Time', 'Delivery Date', 'Service Level'}}}
```

I am storing all the keys of a dictionary in a list as below

```
check_list = ["test", "shipmentInfo", "Ready Date","Ready Time","Delivery Date","Service Level"]
```

I am writing a simple condition to check if every key given in the dictionary is present in my list. If any key is not present it should say that key is missing

```
missing = [field for field in x if field not in check_list]
   if len(missing) == 0:
       print("All values are entered")
   else:
       [print(f"Missing value: {field}") for field in missing]
```

the problem with my condition is, it is only checking if 'test' is present in the dictionary. It is not checking for the main keys that I need("Ready Date","Ready Time","Delivery Date","Service Level").
If i remove one value from the list, like delivery date

```
("Ready Date","Ready Time","Service Level")
```

the logic I use will give me this result

```
All values are entered
```

How to fetch ("Ready Date","Ready Time","Delivery Date","Service Level") and compare it with my list?

Comment: Your innermost item `{'Ready Date', 'Ready Time', 'Delivery Date', 'Service Level'}` is a `set`, not a `dict`...

Comment: @user32882 How can I access those items? I am a beginner in python and unable to code that part

Comment: You can't .... a set is not meant to be subscripted... A better question is why do you have a set in there?

Comment: @user32882: It is JSON format response, I receive from users through API and it stored like that. I have to check if that each element exisits in my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values `{'Ready Date', 'Ready Time', 'Delivery Date', 'Service Level'}` are composing a set, they are not keys of an inner dictionary, but it is still possible to check if they exist in the original dictionary `x`:

The implemented `dictionary_to_list` function, takes the original dictionary `x` and flattens it into a list that contains all keys and values of it to a list.

```
x = {'test': {'shipmentInfo': {'Ready Date', 'Ready Time', 'Delivery Date', 'Service Level'}}}
check_list = ["test", "shipmentInfo", "Ready Date","Ready Time","Delivery Date","Service Level"]


def dictionary_to_list_helper(d, l):
    for k, v in d.items():
        l.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, set):
            for item in v:
                l.append(item)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            dictionary_to_list_helper(v, l)

def dictionary_to_list(d):
    l = []
    dictionary_to_list_helper(d, l)
    return l

missing = [field for field in dictionary_to_list(x) if field not in check_list]
if len(missing) == 0:
   print("All values are entered")
else:
   [print(f"Missing value: {field}") for field in missing]
```